# Troubles with Ubuntu Touch installation on Nexus 4

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Following [the official Ubuntu Touch installation instructions](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/) I always get stuck in bootloader "downloading..." while terminal shows:

```
mizz@Miz:~$ ubuntu-device-flash touch --channel=ubuntu-touch/stable/ubuntu --bootstrap
2016/11/23 11:04:44 Expecting the device to be in the bootloader... waiting
2016/11/23 11:04:44 Device is |mako|
2016/11/23 11:04:45 Flashing version 33 from ubuntu-touch/stable/ubuntu channel and server https://system-image.ubuntu.com to device mako
22.61 MB / 22.61 MB [===] 100.00 % 1.28 MB/s 
52.70 MB / 52.70 MB [===] 100.00 % 1.99 MB/s 
298.13 MB / 298.13 MB [===] 100.00 % 4.39 MB/s
```

(other times just witout the last three lines.)

After turning the phone off and on everything (boot+recovery+AndroidOS) works normal again.

---

Alternatively, following [the dualboot installation instructions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/DualBootInstallation) I also get stuck in bootloader "downloading..." while terminal shows:

```
mizz@Miz:~$ ./dualboot.sh
No device ID specified, picking first available device
Waiting for device 016fd3888d0d4647 to install Ubuntu installer to.
Detected connected Nexus 4
Downloading recovery for mako
ls: cannot access 'recovery-mako-6.0.4.3.img': No such file or directory
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 8400k  100 8400k    0     0  2735k      0  0:00:03  0:00:03 --:--:-- 2735k
Downloaded file has size: 8601600
Dafaulting to auto action
Device 016fd3888d0d4647 bin: , xbin: , CM_DEVICE: mako
selecting UPDATE mode
Downloading Ubuntu Installer application package
ls: cannot access 'UPDATE-UbuntuInstaller.zip': No such file or directory
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 2266k  100 2266k    0     0   418k      0  0:00:05  0:00:05 --:--:--  467k
Downloaded file has size: 2321175
install_ubuntu_installer<<
Dev:016fd3888d0d4647: Rebooting to bootloader
Waiting for device to be connected in normal or recovery mode
Dev:016fd3888d0d4647: Waiting for fastboot to be ready
downloading 'boot.img'...
```

Again, after turning the phone off and on everything works normal again.

---

Any ideas why am I getting stuck there, please?

PS Cyanogenmod 13 with CM SuperUser and new TWRP installed, USB debugging allowed, bootloader unlocked, over 3GB of free space on the device.

---

Edit: Afterwards I used MultiROM Manager app from Google Play to install Ubuntu Touch in dual boot mode and now both OSes work fine.

Comment: Have you tried installing it using Magic Device Tool? It's really simple and never let me down: https://github.com/MariusQuabeck/magic-device-tool